# 148:cube cell write status element is consolidated error

Tags: cognos-tm1

While changing the data in TM 1 template ,I am getting below error.

> 148:cube cell write status element is consolidated error.

I have tried reloading the template again but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you tried to write to a consolidated ("C") element. Depending on your acutal TM1 version (btw: which one are you using) automatic spreading while entering values on C-elements is not possibile.

Be sure you checked all dimension coordinates to only target N (or S) elements.
Hope this works.